# Is a puppet node allowed to query anything?

Tags: security, puppet

If a client node get compromised, can it ask the Puppet master anything, like the password for the other clients account password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest is secure. So are variables declared inside the manifest.

Things that may need security precautions:

- files that are available via `source => "puppet:///..."`
- hiera values, if your hierarchy relies on facts such as `hostname`

Background is - an agent can impersonate another one only to a certain extent, i.e. by manipulating the `hostname` and `fqdn` facts etc.

The `certname` fact cannot be overridden, so the master will never use a "foreign" `node` block for a rogue agent. Make sure that Hiera only relies on `$certname`. Try and configure the builtin `fileserver` to protect private files from rogue agents via `auth.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer. By default, a node can only acess to its resources, so it can't query anything.